# Application getting closed on the : setComponentEnabledSetting() with COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED and PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11

*Application getting closed on the call of*

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, DefaultLauncher.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**With 10 and 10+ OS**

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't know what can I do!!

Comment: This is a system default behavior, the system refreshes itself  whenever a new launcher is set, which causes this thing in the 10 and above

Comment: So, What can I do?

Comment: I test it on emulator android 9 and get the same result(app getting closed)

Comment: For 9 it might due to the emulator, with the device I have never faced this issue,
For a solution show some message, so the user knows what's happened.

Comment: @Drim Were u able to find any solution?